# Beginner WCF Client/Server Loosely Coupled Design

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server

I have a WCF Service that communicates with a single client. My goal is to have a client that is updated as little as possible, and should not need to be updated when I add new properties/methods to my Service.

My first approach, below, breaks my goal since when adding a property/methods to my Service, I need to update the Service Reference of the client.

The structure of the WCF Service DLL looks like the following:

```
- IMyService.cs
- MyService.cs
    - Hardware Interface 1.cs
    - Hardware Interface 2.cs
    - Definitions.cs
```

Within each hardware interface I have multiple properties and methods that I would like the client to access.

Currently, the way I expose these properties/methods to the client is through the following IMyService methods:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    void MethodA(Object msg);
    [OperationContract]
    void MethodB(Object msg);
    [OperationContract]
    void MethodC(Object msg);

    [OperationContract]
    Object Hardware1GetProperty(Hardware1Property propID);  //large switch case for all properties
    [OperationContract]
    void Hardware1SetProperty(Hardware1Property propID, Object val);    //large switch case for all properties


    [OperationContract]
    Object Hardware2GetProperty(Hardware2Property propID);  //large switch case for all properties
    [OperationContract]
    void Hardware2SetProperty(Hardware2Property propID, Object val);    //large switch case for all properties
}
```

Where Hardware1Property and Hardware2Property are enums stored in Definitions.cs with the following structure:

```
public enum Hardware1Property : uint
{
    PropertyA,
    PropertyB,
    PropertyC,
}
```

Since the Client can access the enums Hardware1Property and Hardware2Property, I thought this would be a good approach since the Client would not have to store a list of all properties on the Service. So the client can get the value of a property by doing the following, for example:

```
MyVar = MyClient.Proxy.Hardware1GetProperty(Hardware1GetProperty.PropertyA);
```

How can I improve this design?

- Are DataContracts the way to go, and if yes how can I implement them?
  (I have never used them before)
- Should I move to a Name Value Pair model for accessing properties? Such that everything is done through Strings and not enums?
- Can I use similar approaches for calling methods?

Answer (score 0):

Not a good approach AFAIK. You are not using weak typed objects and this code will be prone to lot of exceptions. You will also have to use Reflection which will harm performance if not handled properly. You should be using DataContract here.

Read up on MSDN about the DataContract. It may be worth reading initial chapters of a WCF book or some beginners tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to have the ability to change the object types being passed without recompiling the client. Will I lose this functionality with `DataContracts`?